# Using Blast+ with a local database

Tags: database, blast, ncbi

i am currently working on a Blast step using Blast+ but i don't get any hits as a result (I should though because the sequences i blast are in my database file).

I know I am doing something not correctly and would be glad if anyone could sent me on the right track.

This is my code i am using:

Making Database:

`makeblastdb -in input.fasta -parse_seqids -blastdb_version 5 -title "Database1" -dbtype prot`

Blasting:

`blastp -db my_dbfile.fasta -query my_query.txt`

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your makeblastdb command you should either use:

```
blastp -db input.fasta -query my_query.txt
```

Or rename the makeblastdb output files:

```
makeblastdb -in input.fasta -parse_seqids -blastdb_version 5 -title "Database1" -dbtype prot -out my_dbfile.fasta
```